# How to separate legends as different subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I was able to write the code for displaying everything in the same plot:

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.FacetGrid(data, hue="status", height=5) \
   .map(plt.scatter, "age", "year") \
   .add_legend()
plt.show()
```

The output is like:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trz8B.png)

But I want to separate the legends in different plot with each legend as a heading for each subplot basically like this:
[Subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cajcq.png)

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut Sorry but I was learning these things as a part of machine learning basics so I thought to add that.

Comment: No worries; for the future, keep in mind that the tags have to do only with the content of the question, not its (general) context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two subplots, don't use `hue=`, use `col='status'` instead.

You can refer to [the documentation for `FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html?highlight=facetgrid) that shows examples of the different parameters and their function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.FacetGrid(data, col="status", height=5) \
   .map(plt.scatter, "age", "year") \
   .add_legend()
plt.show()
```